# Инициализация массива указателей

Tags: c++, c, qt

Разбираюсь в чужом коде. Насколько правомерно так инициировать:

```
DataArray<unsigned char> *m_Control[CONTROLINDEX_COUNT] = {0};
```

Вообще почему не так например:

```
DataArray<unsigned char> *m_Control[CONTROLINDEX_COUNT] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

где

```
#pragma once

/// \brief A class template for a simple array with a fixed size.

template <class T> class DataArray
{
public:
   DataArray(unsigned int size);
   ~DataArray();

   T *data();
   T operator[](unsigned int index);

   unsigned int getSize() const;

protected:
   T *array;          ///< Pointer to the array holding the data
   unsigned int size; ///< Size of the array (Number of variables of type T)
};

/// \brief Initializes the data array.
/// \param size Size of the data array.
template <class T> DataArray<T>::DataArray(unsigned int size)
{
   this->array = new T[size];
   for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; ++index)
      this->array[index] = 0;

   this->size = size;
}


/// \brief Deletes the allocated data array.
template <class T> DataArray<T>::~DataArray()
{
   delete[] this->array;
}


/// \brief Returns a pointer to the array data.
/// \return The internal data array.
template <class T> T *DataArray<T>::data()
{
   return this->array;
}


/// \brief Returns array element when using square brackets.
/// \return The array element.
template <class T> T DataArray<T>::operator[](unsigned int index)
{
   return this->array[index];
}


/// \brief Gets the size of the array.
/// \return The size of the command in bytes.
template <class T> unsigned int DataArray<T>::getSize() const
{
   return this->size;
}введите сюда код
```

и

```
enum ControlIndex {
    CONTROLINDEX_SETOFFSET,
    CONTROLINDEX_SETRELAYS,
    CONTROLINDEX_SETVOLTDIV_CH1,
    CONTROLINDEX_SETVOLTDIV_CH2,
    CONTROLINDEX_SETTIMEDIV,
    CONTROLINDEX_ACQUIIRE_HARD_DATA,
    CONTROLINDEX_COUNT
};
```

Comment: Что вызвало ваш вопрос? Откуда возникли сомнения в правомерности?

Comment: я просто не смог понять как читать данную конструкцию

Answer (score 6):

Все совершенно правомерно.

Не совсем ясно, зачем вы поставили на свой вопрос тэг [C], но в языке С инициализатор `{ 0 }` является фактически идиоматическим универсальным нулевым инициализатором, который может использоваться для инициализации нулем/нулями чего угодно.

Ваш второй вариант совершенно не приемлем. Вся идея использования именованной константы `CONTROLINDEX_COUNT` заключается в том, чтобы абстрагироваться от ее фактического значения, а ваше `{0,0,0,0,0,0}` достигает прямо противоположного эффекта. Здесь должно быть именно `{ 0 }`, а ни в коем случае не `{0,0,0,0,0,0}`.

Более того, в С++ коде в данном случае даже уместнее было бы написать

```
DataArray<unsigned char> *m_Control[CONTROLINDEX_COUNT] = {};
```

Эффект такого инициализатора в данном случае не отличается от `{ 0 }`, т.е. получается массив нулевых указателей.

P.S. Определение шаблонного класса `DataArray` тут ни к чему, ибо рассматриваемый массив содержит просто указатели.

Comment: хорошо. Наткнулся еще на такой момент - как правильно читать сей синтаксис: 1) создаются CONTROLINDEX_COUNT указателей на такой то тип - DataArray<unsigned char>? Правильно? 2) И все эти укказатели инициируются 0

Comment: @Fynjy: Да, именно так. Только имейте в виду, что `= { 0 }` буквально означает "проинициализировать только самый первый указатель нулевым". А далее вступает в действие правило: если в массиве проинициализирована только часть, то остаток автоматически обнуляется.

Comment: а где Вы берете эту инфу? В стандарте на С++?